# Result for last element of the array not processed in Node promise.each

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a code piece to run through a list of elements in an array (mysql hosts to be precise) and the task is to iterate through each element in the array - connect to mysql using the element(hostname), run a query against it and have the results in a json.

The result for the last element is not captured in the final array, while the others are.

Below are the config array and snippet

Config :

```
config.mysql.list = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3' , 'host1'];
```

The hostname can be repeated. The count of result objects in the response should be equivalent to the number of elements in the array.

```
const config  = require('../../config.js');

//For RESTful API
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const promise=require('bluebird');
//For MySQL connection
const mysql   = require('mysql');

promise.promisifyAll(config);
promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql/lib/Connection').prototype);
promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql/lib/Pool').prototype);

//Home page venue type wise breakup
router.get('/databaseRecords',function(req,res){
  // Some vars
 let arrStatus =[];
 // Build the connection
 function getConnection(serverHost){
  // Setup the MySQL connection
  let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : serverHost,
    user     : config.mysql.user,
    password : config.mysql.password,
    database : config.mysql.database
  });
  // <- note the second return
  return connection.connectAsync().return(connection);
}
    promise.each(config.mysql.list,function(serverHost) {
      //Create connection
      return getConnection(serverHost).then(function(conn){
        // Slave status
        let qry = 'SELECT * FROM tableName limit 1';
          // Response ?
          conn.queryAsync(qry).then(function(rows){
            let strresponse = JSON.stringify(rows);
            let jsonresponse = JSON.parse(strresponse);
            jsonresponse[0].whichRec=serverHost;
            arrStatus.push(jsonresponse[0]);
            //done
            conn.endAsync();
      });
    });
  }).then(function(){
    // Emit the response
    res.json({'data':arrStatus});
  }).catch(function(err){
    let respErr  = JSON.parse(err.error);
    res.json({'Error':respErr});
  });
});
//Export routes
module.exports = router;
```

A bit confused as to what I am really missing in the code snippet.

Comment: Would putting `return` infront of  `conn.queryAsync(qry)` solve the problem?

Comment: you have host1 twice in your example. Is that error only in your snippet?

Comment: @PierreMallet that is just an example.. Can be anyhost. However,  the result for the last host is not considered. Also, there is no error as such,  just that the result of the last iteration is not captured in the final output.

Comment: I think Skyler comment is the key: you don't return before conn.queryAsync ( thus the promise return "undefined" and is resolved immediately) so the "promise.each" resolves after the last getConnection and not after the last queryAsync. Then the last result is not yet pushed in the arrStatus when you do your res.json

Comment: @Skyler will check this and let you know

Comment: @Skyler that worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ValerianPereira Can you  accept my answer below, if it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put return in front of conn.queryAsync(qry). You need to return the promise returned from conn.queryAsync. Hope this helps.